# Multiple json calls

Tags: fullcalendar

I can retrieve resources but I can't do the same with it's events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    ...
    defaultView: 'resourceDay',
    resources: 'LDAPRetornarSalesEdifici?edifici=' + $('#edifici').val(),
    events: 'SQLRetornarHorariEdificiJSON?edifici=' + $('#edifici').val(),
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
    ...
```

Both LDAPRetornarSalesEdifici and SQLRetornarSalesEdifici are servlets. The first one load my resources (meeting rooms) and the second one doesn't work.

This is the output of LDAPRetornarSalesEdifici:

```
[{"id":"3PB.C21","name":"Aula Félix Serratosa"},{"id":"3PB.C31","name":"Terrassa Administració"}]
```

This is the output of SQLRetornarSalesEdifici:

```
[{"id":"65985","title":"Seminari Dep. Quimica-NO ES FA (Eva Poca) - Seminari Quimica","start": {"year":2014,"month":9,"dayOfMonth":30,"hourOfDay":9,"minute":30,"second":0},"end":{"year":2014,"month":9,"dayOfMonth":30,"hourOfDay":10,"minute":30,"second":0},"allDay":false,"url":"ReservaModificarMostrarResultat?id\u003d65985","resourceId":"3PB.C21"},{"id":"63098","title":"Programa Oncologia (Cristina Méndez) - Seminari","start":{"year":2014,"month":9,"dayOfMonth":30,"hourOfDay":15,"minute":30,"second":0},"end":{"year":2014,"month":9,"dayOfMonth":30,"hourOfDay":17,"minute":30,"second":0},"allDay":false,"url":"ReservaModificarMostrarResultat?id\u003d63098","resourceId":"3PB.C21"}]
```

Firebug returns this error from jquery-1.9.1.min.js after receive event data:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
...===n||"function"!==n&&(0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in e)}r=b(o);var _={}...
```

Comment: I replaced Id and resourceId values to int but nothing change.

Comment: Don't think you can input start and end like that. Try using ISO format

Comment: @RichardHermanson, the output is now [{"id":66138,"title":"IRB Albericio (Jan Spengler) - Seminari grup","start":"**2014-11-04T15:00:00**","end":"**2014-11-04T16:00:00**","allDay":false,"url":"ReservaModificarMostrarResultat?id\u003d66138","resourceId":1}] and still doesn't work.

Comment: Try setting events to a "hard coded object" with output that you expect from your servlet. Post an example jsfiddle that's not working or play around with it yourself until it works